# How to replace text in a string through powershell?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have a file(local.tfvars) which consists of:

```
Car {  
}  
Bus {
}
```

Now I want to replace car in this file with

```
Car {
  Audi,
  Mercedes,
}  
Bus {
}
```

through the script.

I am fetching the local file through

```
 $localfile = Get-Content -Path ("local.tfvars")
```

after that I am using:

```
  $localfile.replace("Car","Car{`n Audi,Mercedes)
```

Which should give me the output as:

```
Car {
  Audi,  
  Mercedes,
}
Bus {
}
```

But the output doesn't seem to come in this way, the output that I am getting is:

```
Car {
  Audi,
}
Bus {  
}
Car {
  Mercedes,
}
Bus { 
}
```

See here these are getting printed twice which I don't want.

Comment: It is generally a bad practice to use regular expressions for peeking and poking in structured text. Instead, use the related parsers as in this case (afaik [`.tfvars`](https://spacelift.io/blog/terraform-tfvars) are [`Json`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) files) the [`ConvertFrom/ConvertTo-Json`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) cmdlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your example looks like JSON, it is not, so what you can do here is to read the file as single multiline string and use regex operator `-replace` on its content.

The easies way to retain the replacement's (multiline) format is by using a Here-String:

```
# replace with
$newCars = @'
Car {
  Audi,
  Mercedes,
} 
'@

# find the empty Cars node and replace it with above $newCars
# if you also want the output on screen, append switch `PassThru` to the Set-Content command
(Get-Content -Path "local.tfvars" -Raw) -replace '(?m)^Car\s*\{\s*}', $newCars | Set-Content -Path "local.tfvars"
```

Result:

```
Car {
  Audi,
  Mercedes,
}   
Bus {
}
```

Regex details:

```
(?m)       Match the remainder of the regex with the options: ^ and $ match at line breaks (m)
^          Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
Car        Match the characters “Car” literally
\s         Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\{         Match the character “{” literally
\s         Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
}          Match the character “}” literally
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
$result = @'
{

Car {
}
Bus {
}

}
'@

$result = $result.Replace("Car {", "Car {`r`nAudi,`r`nMercedes,`r")

$result
```

Comment: Is there any method you know?

Comment: It is working but I am not able to fetch $result from local.tfvars file

Comment: so you want to replace the existing file with the newly updated result?

Comment: Yes, you got that right

Comment: you can just pipe $result | Set-Content -Path "local.tfvars" on the last line.